# $(...).fancybox is not a function and can't read property 'msie'

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I've the latest version of jQuery and trying to use fancybox, but these messages always appear:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined
>
> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fancybox is not a function

I tried `jQuery.noConflict()` too, and my jQuery is loaded before the fancybox.js

Comment: Can you please post your HTML and JavaScript, the most likely reason for this error is that the JQuery library is not loaded correctly.

Comment: It looks like you haven't included the fancybox library and are using a version of jQuery from the 2.x branch which does not have the browser sniffing methods included.

Comment: actually `$.browser` was deprecated: 1.3 and removed: 1.9  and is available only through the jQuery.migrate plugin - From jquery docs https://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/

Comment: i'm using jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js and jquery-1.12.0.min.js. Jquery is loaded first, then fancybox.js and then script.js where i try to use fancybox() function

Comment: Any errors in your console? @BidzinaAivazashvili

Comment: Yeah, these errors appear in my console.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fancybox is not a function

Comment: Jquery migrate plugin helped me ! Thanks guys, especially to you ! @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using the new fancybox instead?  http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

This is the first couple lines in the jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js file

```
;(function($) {
    var tmp, loading, overlay, wrap, outer, content, close, title, nav_left, nav_right,    
        selectedIndex = 0, selectedOpts = {}, selectedArray = [], currentIndex = 0, currentOpts = {}, currentArray = [],    
        ajaxLoader = null, imgPreloader = new Image(), imgRegExp = /\.(jpg|gif|png|bmp|jpeg)(.*)?$/i, swfRegExp = /[^\.]\.(swf)\s*$/i,    
        loadingTimer, loadingFrame = 1,    
        titleHeight = 0, titleStr = '', start_pos, final_pos, busy = false, fx = $.extend($('<div/>')[0], { prop: 0 }),    
        isIE6 = $.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 7 && !window.XMLHttpRequest,
```

It'll fail here

```
isIE6 = $.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 7 && !window.XMLHttpRequest,
```

because `jquery.browser` has been removed as of 1.9 unless you include jquery.migrate https://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/

Since it fails there - $.fancybox never get's a chance to get declared so that's why you're getting the 2 errors.

The new fancybox doesn't use `jQuery.browser` and is using `IE =  navigator.userAgent.match(/msie/i)` instead

So you have to choose 1 of the below

1. use new fancybox
2. use an older jquery library
3. include jquery.migrate